# Operand should contain 2 column(s) error in mysql NOT IN

Tags: mysql

I want to delete all records from mysql table except few I use below query

```
 DELETE FROM table_name WHERE (user_id,year) NOT IN
 (
  '1','2009',
  '3','2010',
  '7','2007'
 );
```

But it shows error as **Operand should contain 2 column(s)**  Is it correct way to use not in on multiple columns in same table

Comment: Why down vote ? What is wrong in question

Comment: Also wonder one close vote under off topic. Is it not related to programming ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax is wrong, it should be

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE (user_id, year) NOT IN
(
  ('1', '2009'),
  ('3', '2010'),
  ('7', '2007')
);
```

Notice the added parenthesis around each tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Id sould be unique so

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id NOT IN
 (
  1,
  3,
  7
 );
```

sould work

Comment: It should be unique in the "users" table, but we do not really now from which table are currently deleting.